# update a tuple key in dictionary with another dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have:

```
edge_mask = {(0, 2): 0.7, (0, 6): 0.4}
```

and this:

```
labels: {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'E', 5: 'F', 6: 'G'}
```

I need to update the dictionary:

```
edge_mask = {('A', 'C'): 0.7, ('A', 'G'): 0.4}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```py
edge_mask = {(0, 2): 0.7, (0, 6): 0.4}
labels = {0: "A", 1: "B", 2: "C", 3: "D", 4: "E", 5: "F", 6: "G"}

edge_mask = {(labels[a], labels[b]): v for (a, b), v in edge_mask.items()}
print(edge_mask)
```

Prints:

```
{('A', 'C'): 0.7, ('A', 'G'): 0.4}
```